# URL direct depending on form selection

Tags: forms, url, redirect

I have a simple form which I would like to redirect the user to a specific URL within my site, depending on the value they have selected. So far I have this but instead of directing to one of the 4 urls, I instead get "http://mydomain.com/?ApplianceType=americano.html&sub=Submit" in my address bar:

```
<form name="form1" method="get">
        <p>
          <label>
            <select name="ApplianceType" id="ApplianceType">
              <option value="americano.html">American Fridge Freezer</option>
              <option value="freezer.html">Freezer only</option>
              <option value="fridge.html">Fridge only</option>
              <option value="fridgefreezer.html">Fridge/Freezer</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="Submit">
          </label>
        </p>
      </form>
```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: I suspect that you are merely requesting to process the data via the `GET` method. You will need some client-side Javascript or any of its libraries to change your form's `action` attribute on 'value change' to a specified URL. Are you currently using any Javascript?

Comment: Thank you. A friend suggested the code below, but to be completely honest, I have no idea how to impliment it (it's on my page but I'm not sure how to run it when the submit button is clicked):

<script type="text/javascript">
function setLocation(element) {
            document.forms[0].action = element.
value
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can change your HTML:

```
<form name="form1" id="yourForm" action="americano.html" method="get"> <!-- Added an ID to the form, and set the default value of `action` to 'americano.html'. -->
    <p>
      <label>
        <select name="ApplianceType" id="ApplianceType" onchange="setURL(this)"> <!-- Assigned the `select` to run the function on value change. -->
          <option value="americano.html">American Fridge Freezer</option>
          <option value="freezer.html">Freezer only</option>
          <option value="fridge.html">Fridge only</option>
          <option value="fridgefreezer.html">Fridge/Freezer</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="Submit">
      </label>
    </p>
</form>
```

Then use the following Javascript function:

```
<script>
    function setURL(selectedValue)
    {    
        var element = document.getElementById('yourForm'); // Change 'yourForm' to the actual ID you assign on your form.
        element.action = selectedValue.value;
    }
</script>
```

Please take note of the comments in the code.